# Vim textwidth comma indent problem

Tags: vim, text-editor, indentation

If i set the following option in Vim,

```
set textwidth=80
```

the text will break at 80 characters. This works, but the problem is if a comma (,) is on the end of a line, Vim indents the next line. What can I do to avoid this behaviour?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You probably have C style indenting on. `:set nocindent` should do the trick

Comment: As a reference for others, **smartindent** or **autoindent** are also relevant. See :help C-indenting for details.

Answer (score -3):

Edit your `.vimrc` and comment `set fo=...` out.